# What is the order of destruction for static objects and global objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

If in a program I create a meyer's singleton and an object that uses this meyer's singleton in both its constructor and destructor, things are okay as long as the object that uses meyer's singleton is destroyed before the singleton itself (like when it is in a function scope).

Now if I make the same object global, I see seg fault. The reason is that the singleton gets destroyed before the global object.

Is this a compiler defined behaviour or standard defined behaviour? Is there any way we can modify this behaviour?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: The order of [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) and [destruction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) is partially defined. The most important part is that the order between [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) is not defined.

Comment: The destruction order is exactly the reverse of construction (in order of completion), but the construction order between translation units is unspecified. Meyer's singleton should protect against exactly this problem, so it sounds like your singleton implementation has at least one problem. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: See [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof) (which also applies for destruction).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the order of destruction for static objects and global objects?

The order of destruction of objects with static storage duration is the inverse of the order of their initialisation.

> Is this a compiler defined behaviour or standard defined behaviour?

The inverse order of destruction is standard.

The order of initialisation of non-local static objects is the same as the order of declaration within a single translation unit. The order across translation units is unspecified. Local static objects are initialised when the execution first passes their declaration.

> Is there any way we can modify this behaviour?

You can influence the order of initialisation of non-local static objects within a translation unit by reordering their declarations. You can influence the order of initialisation of local static objects by calling the function earlier or later. The order of destruction is indirectly influenced by changing the order of initialisation.

You cannot influence to order of initialisation of non-local objects with static storage duration between translation units, and you must not rely on that order.

Comment: You wrote "The order of initialisation of non-local static objects is the same as the order of declaration within a single translation unit. The order across translation units is unspecified." My question is that "are you talking about static initialization or dynamic initialization" in the above quoted statement? Also can you site the source. Is your statement equivalent to saying "Initialization of static variables in different translation units is indeterminately sequenced." which holds for dynamic initialization.

Comment: @AanchalSharma I'm talking about the dynamic initialisation phase. The order of static initialisation phase (of static objects) is irrelevant as far as I know since it cannot have interdependencies.

Comment: @AanchalSharma The suorce is the C++ standard. See the sections [basic.start.dynamic], [basic.start.term], [stmt.dcl].

Comment: @AanchalSharma `Is your statement equivalent to saying "Initialization of static variables in different translation units is indeterminately sequenced."` Yes. That would be a more technically precise way to say it.